# My audio doesn’t have sides

Tags: logic-pro, audio-editing

I have a mono track. I transform it into stereo using **Utility —> Gain —> Mono -> Stereo**. Pretty easy. Then I choose an plugin that works in MS mode. But when I try to boost a volume level of Sides — I get no result, but when I decrease a level of Mid — it decreases the sound of whole audio. So my audio file doesn’t have Sides. How can I get these Sides into it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Guide: How to add sides to mono file?

Easy! Add a stereo reverb plug-in to a mono track with <kbd>mono –> stereo</kbd>  setting. After this you can use MS equalizers, or use **Center** plugin by Waves to boost sides as I did.

Comment: And did anything useful result?

Comment: @LaurencePayne - I suspect yes, given that s/he answered his/her own question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid converting your mono signal into stereo format doesn't add any stereo information, it just places everything in the centre of the stereo image.   The Sides channel is about stereo position.  If everything is centre, Sides information is zero.

Comment: True, the thing is that I need to boost Sides. So how do I add that information to Mono source?

Comment: A mono source simply doesn't have any side information, it's a single source; essentially 'all mid & no side'.

Comment: Exactly, you would need to record a stereo source to have a stereo image.  What you're asking is sort of like "how can add colour to a black and white image"

Comment: You're asking to boost something that isn't there!  Zero doubled is still zero.